# Event isn't showing in browser for VueJS app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

I'm showing the app in my web browser, but the events section isn't showing the events. My app.js and index.html files are included in my GitHub profile here. https://github.com/HolisticTomboy/events-app-vue.git

Comment: You're writing the app using Vue 1, but you've installed Vue 2. There's no `ready` in Vue 2, use `mounted`. Also, no need for `$set`, just `this.events = events`. Use `splice` instead of `$remove`. `v-repeat` is `v-for`. Basically, if you want to use Vue2, you should read through the updated docs. Or install Vue 1.

Comment: @BertEvans I think this is not even version 1, `v-repeat` was used in `0.x`.But everything you said is correct.

Comment: @BertEvansThanks for your input. I've changed the codes with the "vue-migration-helper" but I may be missing something because that didn't work. At first, I tried searching for a download for Vue 1.0, but not having much luck. I'm still a beginner, so it might be in my face but not noticing it. It seems like it's easier to just change the code since it's a smaller app. Thanks.

Comment: @EliseAllen I made a pull request for your repo that fixes some minor syntax errors that allow your app to work. Otherwise it was good :)

Comment: @BertEvans thanks!! :)